# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '["2"]' for column `stagen`.`imunisasis`.`id_j_imun` at row 1

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

```sql
update `imunisasis` set `id_j_imun` = ["2"], `tgl_imun` = 2023-08-09, `ket_imun` = asdasdsada, `imunisasis`.`updated_at` = 2023-08-09 07:29:27 where `id_imun` = 5
```

I'm having trouble updating data.

**Imunisasi Controller **

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        // menerima data request
        $data = Imunisasi::where('id_imun', $id)->first();
        $data->id_anak   = $request->get('id_anak');
        $data->id_j_imun = $request->get('id_j_imun');
        $data->tgl_imun  = $request->get('tgl_imun');
        $data->booster   = $request->get('booster');
        $data->ket_imun  = $request->get('ket_imun');
        $data->save();

        return redirect()->route('imunisasi')->with(['success' => 'Data Berhasil Di Update']);
    }
```

**Database Imunisasi**

```
Schema::create('imunisasis', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id_imun');
            $table->unsignedInteger('id_anak');
            $table->unsignedInteger('id_j_imun');
            $table->date('tgl_imun');
            $table->string('booster');`your text`
            $table->string('ket_imun')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('id_anak')->references('id_anak')->on('anaks');
            $table->foreign('id_j_imun')->references('id_j_imun')->on('jenis_imunisasis');
        });
```

Comment: you're passing an array with value `["2"]` to your `id_j_imun` but in your migration, it is `unsignedInteger`

Comment: the answer is right in the error message.

Comment: so how to solve it?

Comment: idk how you are passing your data from your form/ajax to your controller. First fix that. If you actually want to set the `id_j_imun` from form/ajax, then implode that in your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you're providing a valid integer value for the `id_j_imun` column.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // menerima data request
    $data = Imunisasi::where('id_imun', $id)->first();
    $data->id_anak   = $request->get('id_anak');
    
    // Make sure the value is cast to an integer
    $data->id_j_imun = (int)$request->get('id_j_imun');
    
    $data->tgl_imun  = $request->get('tgl_imun');
    $data->booster   = $request->get('booster');
    $data->ket_imun  = $request->get('ket_imun');
    $data->save();

    return redirect()->route('imunisasi')->with(['success' => 'Data Berhasil Di Update']);
}
```

Comment: tq sirr , its work